# popup not working with UA and GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, popup

We recently updated our site to to Universal Analytics and GTM. We have a popup that would come up on exiting a page and send events based on the choices. Now if we try to tag the events the popup doesn't work. If we comment out the events the popup works but we don't have any tracking on it. Below is the script how it was originally and worked fine and then the one with the changes that now stops the popup from working.

Before Script that worked:

```
<script>
var goodExit               = false;
var through_onbeforeunload = false;
var count_onbeforeunload   = 1;

function unloadStatus() {
    if(through_onbeforeunload) {
        through_onbeforeunload = false;
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onbeforeunload', 'returned from popup']);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval("unloadStatus()", 500);

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        through_onbeforeunload = true;
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onbeforeunload', 'saw popup', '', count_onbeforeunload++]);

        if(!goodExit) {
            var my_string    = '--------------------------------------------\n';
            my_string       += 'YOUR APPLICATION HAS NOT YET BEEN SUBMITTED!\n';
            my_string       += '--------------------------------------------\n';
            my_string       += 'You are minutes away from completing your application.\n';
            my_string       += 'If you exit this page your information will not be saved.\n';
            my_string       += '\n';
            my_string       += 'CLICK THE STAY ON THIS PAGE BUTTON\n';
            my_string       += 'TO CONTINUE THE APPLICATION PROCESS.\n';
            my_string       += '--------------------------------------------';
            return my_string;
        }
    }

    window.onunload = function() {
        if(through_onbeforeunload) {
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onbeforeunload', 'left through popup']);
        }
    }

    $('.js-app-submit').click(function() {
        goodExit              = true;
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
</script>
```

Below when we implemented UA and GTM we changed the gaq.push to ga('send','event... and everything stopped working.

```
<script>
var goodExit               = false;
var through_onbeforeunload = false;
var count_onbeforeunload   = 1;

function unloadStatus() {
    if(through_onbeforeunload) {
        through_onbeforeunload = false;
         ga(['send', 'event', 'onbeforeunload', 'returned from popup']);
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval("unloadStatus()", 500);

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        through_onbeforeunload = true;
        ga(['send', 'event', 'onbeforeunload', 'saw popup', count_onbeforeunload++]);

        if(!goodExit) {
            var my_string    = '--------------------------------------------\n';
            my_string       += 'YOUR APPLICATION HAS NOT YET BEEN SUBMITTED!\n';
            my_string       += '--------------------------------------------\n';
            my_string       += 'You are minutes away from completing your application.\n';
            my_string       += 'If you exit this page your information will not be saved.\n';
            my_string       += '\n';
            my_string       += 'CLICK THE STAY ON THIS PAGE BUTTON\n';
            my_string       += 'TO CONTINUE THE APPLICATION PROCESS.\n';
            my_string       += '--------------------------------------------';
            return my_string;
        }
    }

    window.onunload = function() {
        if(through_onbeforeunload) {
            ga(['send', 'event', 'onbeforeunload', 'left through popup']);
        }
    }

    $('.js-app-submit').click(function() {
        goodExit              = true;
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
</script>
```

If we comment out the Google tags the pop up works but nothing gets tracked. Unfortunately this lives on the page and the analytics are in GTM but we tested by adding analytics directly on the site and it still did not work.

Any help/suggestions, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax used to send the event is incorrect. There should not be any square brackets, so for example for your first event in the unloadStatus function, it should be:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'onbeforeunload', 'returned from popup');
```

The same for the rest.

Comment: Such an easy one I looked at that over and over. Can't believe I didn't see that.
Thanks so much I will try that today and see if that works.

Comment: Tried taking out the brackets and still didn't work. Now it shows a Console Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected String

Comment: When putting the code back in this time the commas came out. Added those back in and it worked. Thank You nyuen

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean the commas came out?